# Re-write existing pdf via iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

is here a possibility to make given pdf-file blank and re-write new data to this file? I know that it is possible to trim document deleting pages from the middle. But I didn't find any ways to clear document at all. Thank you

Comment: If all you're doing is making a pages blank, why not just make a new pdf? If you want to blank specific pages in a document, you can always delete and insert blank pages.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Samuel Huylebroeck, if you are looking to create new content then just create new pages or a new document.

If you really want to though, you should be able to remove the existing content of a page in a PDF by going through some of the lower level APIs that deal with things like Content Streams (Content Streams are not specific to iText so if you are looking to learn more about PDF in general you can read about these anywhere).

I don't know whether iText will allow you to set a pages content stream to null though or the content streams data to null, it would be quick to try though if you are really committed to this approach for whatever you are trying to achieve.